# get count of cart items in Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page and i want to get the count of items in cart i have added this in MasterPageBase

```
public int CartTotalCount
{
   get
   {
     CartItemCollection ccart=new CartItemCollection();
     return ccart.Count;
   }
}
```

And now how could i assign this to a variable so that i could show it in a span or div to show the count along with cart image

Comment: ccart is a new item in this way it is always zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var totalitems = <%= CartTotalCount %>;
```

now you can assign it to div from here

or just from aspx code

```
<div id="cartcount">Items in cart: <%= CartTotalCount %></div>
```

Comment: I want to use it in jquery like this      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var toa = <%= CartTotalCount %>   
        });
      
    </script> is it possible

Comment: @Vivekh you can not access propeties in jquery, well in that case you need to use a hidden field to have count of items in cart, then you can change the hidden field value through javascript or jquery

Comment: This should totally work just fine: <script> $(document).ready(function () { var toa = <%= CartTotalCount %>; }); </script>

Comment: @alejosoft by this he can access the value of that variable only, he needs to change it too.

Comment: @Rex you can totally "access" code behind properties in the markup to render javascript code.

Comment: @Rex He is not talking any where about changing the values. He wants to display it. Please read the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this on your Master page markup:

```
<div>Items in cart: <%= CartTotalCount %></div>
```

I hope this helps.